# PHP, date("DATE_COOKIE") echoing odd result

Tags: php, date

**Code:**

```
echo ("<br><br>The date is: " . date("DATE_COOKIE"));
```

**Result:**

> The date is: ThuPMUTCE_C+0000+0000K0E

**Question:**
Can anyone explain this odd result? Maybe I am using the date wrong. I looked at the referenced on [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp).

Comment: Don't put quotes around constants.

Comment: Please add that as an awsner

Comment: On a side note: W3 Schools is not very good for source. php.net has way better documentation and examples on everything in multiple languages

Comment: I will take that into consideration for future learning, Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get a better result, use `new DateTime(DATE_COOKIE)` or `new DateTime(COOKIE)`. 
That function return a datetime in a format like: **Monday, 15-Aug-2005 15:52:01 UTC**.

Here you can get more help [The DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: The `DateTime` constructor expects a timestamp value, not a date format specification. If anything you want `(new DateTime)->format(DATE_COOKIE)`.

Answer (score 1):

As Sammitch said in a comment on my question, To avoid this odd result don't put quotes around constants.
In other words I had to remove the quotes from the DATE_COOKIE.